# Wired connection drops out after a while

Tags: pppoe

I get connected to the internet automatically when i turn on my computer I have configured the network from the network manager in the system setting and created a new pppoe connection.

So it gets connected directly when I turn on my computer but after working on net or when I have kept some files on downloads the network gets disconnected or other words connection gets dropped. The message i get is Wired Network is disconnected. And then I cannot reconnect because in the network manager the wired connection gets disappeared so I have to restart my computer to get connected ..

So can anybody help me to configure the network setting of mine.. 
it will be great if anyone can tell me how to set auto redial  ...

Answer (score 1):

if you already have created a pppoe connection, then just run the following command

```
pppoe-start
```

it will start your default pppoe-connection.

to stop a pppoe-connection, run

```
pppoe-stop
```

Comment: i tried but it is of no use when it gets disconnected no able to see any wired connection in my network manager thereafter i have restart my pc